# Evaluating Contrasts in repeated measures ANOVA (SPSS)

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures

I have 6 Treatment groups (A-F, with A as control) and measure parameter A at four time points 1-4.
I am particulary interested in the changes over time depending on the treatment - time*treatment.

To do this, I used "Contrasts" and set the "time" contrast to polynomial, because I want to know if the changes over time between the treatment groups are different.

They are - I get a significant result. However, I want to know between which groups the changes are significant (so to say a kind of Post-hoc test). Is there any possibility to do this besides "calculating all group combinations seperate" ?

If you have any questions regarding the study design, feel free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a meeting with a Biostatistic Professor I can say:
There is no other possibility besides "calculating all group combinations seperate".

If your contrasts are significant, you have to discuss this significance based on individual calculation of the group combinations and based on the profil plots